# Clarified butter to ghee

Tags: ghee

I did not cook my ghee long enough and it doesn’t have the browned toasty flavor. Can I re-cook with another stick of butter to get the toasty butter flavor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I think i undercooked my ghee - can I reboil it?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/77540/i-think-i-undercooked-my-ghee-can-i-reboil-it)

Comment: Did you actually clarify it (remove the solids and water?). If you removed the solids, then you might not be able to turn it into ghee

Comment: @Joe isn't the definition of ghee, butter with the milk solids removed?

Comment: I voted to close, but now see that the suspected duplicate doesn't really answer your question.  I've retracted that, and will add my simple answer below.

Comment: @moscafj I think so, as you’re trying to prep it for long term storage, but there’s the edge case of browned butter where you don’t remove it that I don’t know how fuzzy the classification is

Answer (score 4):

The toasty flavor, as you point out, comes from browning the milk solids before they are removed.  I don't see any downside to adding a new stick of butter and repeating the process.  Depending on how much clarified butter you created initially, it might not be as toasty, but you should get some flavor.  In either case, you are not impacting the functionality of the ghee.  Ghee and clarified butter essentially behave the same way.  Removing the solids allow them to be used with higher heat, eliminating the burning of the solids during cooking.

Comment: Could even add a bit of yogurt.

Comment: a more direct route might be adding some nonfat milk powder - which essentially consists of the same milk solids that you'd be adding the extra butter for in the first place - and browning those in your protoghee, without having to be concerned about diluting the browned flavour in more butterfat

Comment: @Blargant....nice!